# ASE is terminating this process when trying to install the jar file (Msg 5702, Level 10, State 1)

Tags: java, sybase, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

I have an SAP ASE 16 server on a Windows OS.
I have enabled the java service:

```
sp_configure 'enable java'
Parameter Name Default     Memory Used Config Value Run Value    Unit   Type  
-------------- ----------- ----------- ------------ ------------ ------ ------
enable java              0           0            1            1 switch static

Rows affected (1) Time (0.094 s)
```

I have created a basic class to test the service (JDBCExamples.java):

```
import java.sql.*; // JDBC
public class JDBCExamples {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("\n Usage: " + "name secondName \n");
            return;
        }
        try {
            String name = args[0];
            String secondName = args[1].toLowerCase();
            System.out.println("\n HOLA " + name + " " + secondName +" FUNCIONO!!!\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("\n Exception: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have the class file JDBCExamples.class and I make a file [JDBCExamples.jar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dXTlhJShzf8dfAaTUlY3E7REMPuNSptY/view?usp=sharing).

When I try to install the jar file it shows the error message:

```
instjava -f JDBCExamples.jar -SDEFAULT -Uuser -Ppassword -Ddatabase -new  

Server Message:  - Msg 5702, Level 10, State 1:
ASE is terminating this process.
```

I don't see any in [log database](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p7XttJiBIOaU1dQVtyp8LsW0atr9RqBR/view?usp=sharing).

Any idea what the problem is?

Update:
I posted the same problem in https://answers.sap.com/questions/13241081/ase-is-terminating-this-process-when-trying-to-ins.html

In this post suspect the issue is caused by an ASE bug fixed in PL06:

2687973 - NTPCI__exit(1); Native Thread failed to unwind - SAP ASE http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/2687973

I have a trial version and I can not download a newer patch (PL06 at least but recommend PL09 as most recent)

Does anyone have this patch?

Comment: the last few 100 lines of the log show the `instjava` program generating a couple stack traces due to *"...  generated by a storage access violation"*; unfortunately this is a rather generic message; assuming you're installing your java code into the `test_rut` database I'd want to verify no access issues with the OS device(s) this db sits on; can you create a table in the `test_rut` database and perform inserts/updates/deletes against said table? if this causes errors then we'll want to see those error message(s) and any related lines from the ASE log

Comment: I created a table and inserted records into the `test_sut` database and it allowed me to do so without any problems.